# process every line from command output in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

From every line of nmap network scan output I want to store the hosts and their IPs in variables (for further use additionaly the "Host is up"-string):

The to be processed output from nmap looks like:

```
Nmap scan report for samplehostname.mynetwork (192.168.1.45)
Host is up (0.00047s latency).
```

thats my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line
do
  host=$(grep report|cut -f5 -d' ')
  ip=$(grep report|sed 's/^.*(//;s/)$//') 
  printf "Host:$host - IP:$ip"
done < <(nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24)
```

The output makes something I do not understand. It puts the "Host:" at the very beginning, and then it puts "IP:" at the very end, while it completely omits the output of $ip.

The generated output of my script is:

```
Host:samplehostname1.mynetwork
samplehostname2.mynetwork
samplehostname3.mynetwork
samplehostname4.mynetwork
samplehostname5.mynetwork - IP:
```

In separate, the extraction of $host and $ip basically works (although there might a better solution for sure). I can either printf $host or $ip alone.

What's wrong with my script? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two `grep` commands are reading from standard input, which they inherit from the loop, so they also read from `nmap`. `read` gets one line, the first `grep` consumes the rest, and the second `grep` exits immediately because standard input is closed. I suspect you meant to `grep` the contents of `$line`:

```
while IFS='' read -r line
do
  host=$(grep report <<< "$line" |cut -f5 -d' ')
  ip=$(grep report <<< "$line" |sed 's/^.*(//;s/)$//') 
  printf "Host:$host - IP:$ip"
done < <(nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24)
```

However, this is inefficient and unnecessary. You can use `bash`'s built-in regular expression support to extract the fields you want.

```
regex='Nmap scan report for (.*) \((.*)\)'
while IFS='' read -r line
do
  [[ $line =~ $regex ]] || continue
  host=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  ip=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  printf "Host:%s - IP:%s\n" "$host" "$ip"
done < <(nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24)
```

Comment: that's awesome! But now I stuck in implementing the "Host is up" regex ...

Comment: I assume you would want to use something like `up_regex='Host is up \((.*)s latency\)'`? (This would capture only the number; you can adjust the position of the inner parentheses to capture something different.

Comment: I thought of  up_regex='Host is (.*)'    but I don't know how to implement the check into the existing if statement

Comment: To check for `Host  is up` lines as well as `Nmap` lines, change the structure of the line containing `=~` and break it into three `if` clauses: `if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then` followed by the next three lines, then `elif [[ ${line} =~ ${up_regex} ]]; then; latency=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; echo "Latency is $latency"; else; continue; fi`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line
do
  if [[ $(echo $line | grep report) ]];then
    host=$(echo $line | cut -f5 -d' ')
    ip=$(echo $line | sed 's/^.*(//;s/)$//')
    echo "Host:$host - IP:$ip"
  fi
done < <(nmap -sP it-50)
```

Output:

```
Host:it-50 - IP:10.0.0.10
```

I added an if clause to skip unwanted lines.